# Find recommended products for users with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Find recommended products for users with SQL

I have a catalog with products.

As an example:
Name: Product 1
City: Integer (id of the city in table cities)
Product features: Array of integers (each integer - id of product feature in table features )

```
Table products:
id      name        city
1       Product 1   5

Table product_features:
id      product_id  feature_id
1       1           2
2       1           3
3       1           5

Table features:
id      title
2       Mobile
3       Fast
5       External power source
```

Some registered user (id=10) performs search on a website. User searches (using checkboxes or anything else)

Example: Product from city 5 with features 3(Mobile) and 5(External power source)

Search stored in table user_searches:

```
id  user_id     search_city     search_features (string - list of needed features divided by ",")
1   10          5               3,5
2   11          5               2
2   12          7               3,5
2   13          5               5
```

Example:

Later new product added to catalog.I need to find users who need to be notified about this product
If product features matches user search

Example: New product.

```
id      name            city
2       Product 2(new)  5

product_features:
id      product_id  feature_id
5       2           3
6       2           5
```

Some users should be notified about this product

Table user_searches:

```
id  user_id     search_city     search_features
1   10          5               3,5     (should be notified - new product city:5, features:3,5 )
2   11          5               2       (shouldn't be notified - user needs only feature #2)
2   12          7               3,5     (shouldn't be notified - user searched in another city)
2   13          5               5       (should be notified - user needs feature #5 - new product has this feature )
```

I've tried to get array of users who needs notification using SQL query with 'IN' operator
But it's not solves task when user searches more than one feature:

Example:

```
product_features    user_searched
3,5                 3
```

3 IN 3, 5 - works

```
product_features        user_searched
3,5,10,20                   3,5,7,2
```

3, 5, 10, 20 IN 3, 5, 7, 2.... of course it's not working

Also I've tried to store features which every user needs in another table
(1 feature id per row)

```
user_id     feature_id
10          3
10          5
11          3
```

Etc...

But got same incorrect results. My any other ideas looks more silly than previous.

So I need to get array of users who need to be notified about new product if they searched similar products... I think there should be simpler solution but can't find it.

Any ideas...?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Is there only one row for each user in user_searches? Or its like a  history table?

Comment: In MySQL you have the FIND_IN_SET function to search for elements in a string holding a comma-separated list. So you don't need a table for the searched features. If you want a more standard-like solution, then such a table would be appropriate. It would not contain user_id + feature_id, however, but user_search_id + feature_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's see... You are looking up a product and its features to find all searches where

- the searched city matches the product city
- all searched features exist in product features

As to the second point, we select all feature matches and count them. For the match of an element in a string we use find_in_set, for the count we strip the commas from the search string and count the difference in length.

```
select distinct user_id
from user_searches
where id in
(
  select s.id
  from products p
  join product_features pf on pf.product_id = p.id
  join user_searches s on find_in_set (pf.feature_id , s.search_features) > 0 and p.city = s.search_city
  where p.id = 2
  group by s.id
  having count(*) = char_length(s.search_features) - char_length(replace(s.search_features,',','')) + 1
);
```